# Replace a text after a certain pattern that includes quotation marks and commas

Tags: awk, sed

I have the following csv file:

```
"Function","Source","Line","FnCov","C/D Coverage","out of","%"
"sharp_coll_env2bool","../../src/coll/util.c",176,1,1,34,2%
"TreeManager::SortTreeRootsByGroup","../../src/am/tree_manager.cpp",1467,1,1,26,3%
"FabricGraph::MadSendRetry","../../src/am/fabric_graph.cpp",2170,1,1,16,6%
"ibis_log_mad_function","../../src/am/fabric_provider.cpp",93,1,1,12,8%
"__free_context","../../src/external/mellanox/alog/src/core/media/alog_media.c",415,1,2,13,15%
```

I need to remove all the content that comes before the **first** "/src" in the **second cells**:

```
"Function","Source","Line","FnCov","C/D Coverage","out of","%"
"sharp_coll_env2bool","/src/coll/util.c",176,1,1,34,2%
"TreeManager::SortTreeRootsByGroup","/src/am/tree_manager.cpp",1467,1,1,26,3%
"FabricGraph::MadSendRetry","/src/am/fabric_graph.cpp",2170,1,1,16,6%
"ibis_log_mad_function","/src/am/fabric_provider.cpp",93,1,1,12,8%
"__free_context","/src/external/mellanox/alog/src/core/media/alog_media.c",415,1,2,13,15%
```

So far, I tried the following:

```
sed -i -r 's|(["'\''],.*\/src)|"src"|g'
```

which does not handle the quotation marks.

```
awk -F, '{gsub(/\.*src/,"",$2); print}
```

which replaced all content and ruins the file

Comment: On SO we encourage users to post their efforts which they put in order to solve their own problem, do kindly do add so and let us know then. Also you could use search functionality on SO too for looking guidance related to similar kind of questions.

Comment: I have tried using the following commands:
sed -i -r 's|(["'\''],.*\/src)|"src"|g'       - which does not handle the quotation marks.
awk -F, '{gsub(/\.*src/,"",$2); print} - which replaced all content and ruins the file'

Comment: Please add these commands as your efforts in your post, comments are not meant for posting codes

Comment: Try directly without any comma and quotes as you did on `sed` with same `|` separator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Adding more generic solution here, which will  remove text till very first src string only.

```
awk -v s1="\"" -v var="src" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} 
{
  for(j=1;j<=NF;j++){
     val=index($j,var)
     if(val){
       $j=s1 "/src" substr($j,val+3)
       val=""
     }
  }
  val=""
}
1
'  Input_file
```

---

---

Could you please try following. Why I have gone for going field by field solution if in case there are multiple occurrences of `src` it should handle that without issues.

```
awk -v s1="\"" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {for(j=1;j<=NF;j++){if($j~/src/){sub(/.*src/,s1 "/src",$j)}}} 1'  Input_file
```

Comment: @Ofir Michael, Thank you for selecting answer as correct one, please do lemme know in case of any queries

Comment: Your solution is very elegant, but remove more than the first "/src/". Is there any adjustment I can do to remove only the first one"

Comment: awk: BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{for(j=1;j<=NF;j++){val=index($j,var) if(val){$j=s1 "/src" substr($j,val+3) val=""}} val=""}1
awk:                                                                                                 ^ syntax error

Comment: @OfirMichael, Not clear since back ticks were not added, could you please open a chat room now? We both can talk on this one then.

Answer (score 1):

Simply :

```
sed 's,[^"]*src,/src,' <file>
```

(use `-i` option to replace content on file, `g` at the end if you need to replace more than 1 `../src` per line)

Output :

```
"Function","Source","Line","FnCov","C/D Coverage","out of","%"
"sharp_coll_env2bool","/src/coll/util.c",176,1,1,34,2%
"TreeManager::SortTreeRootsByGroup","/src/am/tree_manager.cpp",1467,1,1,26,3%
"FabricGraph::MadSendRetry","/src/am/fabric_graph.cpp",2170,1,1,16,6%
"ibis_log_mad_function","/src/am/fabric_provider.cpp",93,1,1,12,8%
"__free_context","/src/external/mellanox/alog/src/core/media/alog_media.c",415,1,2,13,15%
```

For something more robust, you can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk).

---

**Edit :**

> Now it removes more than the first "/src/". Is there any adjustment I
>   can do to remove only the first one? – Ofir Michael 1 hour ago

You can use perl for non-greedy regex :

```
perl -pe 's,[^"]*?src,/src,' <file>
```

Input :

```
"Function","Source","Line","FnCov","C/D Coverage","out of","%"
"sharp_coll_env2bool","../../src/coll/util.c",176,1,1,34,2%
"TreeManager::SortTreeRootsByGroup","../../src/am/tree_manager.cpp",1467,1,1,26,3%
"FabricGraph::MadSendRetry","../../src/am/fabric_graph.cpp",2170,1,1,16,6%
"ibis_log_mad_function","../../src/am/fabric_provider.cpp",93,1,1,12,8%
"__free_context","../../src/external/mellanox/alog/src/core/media/alog_media.c",415,1,2,13,15%
"FabricUpdateType2Char","../mtrswgwork/dmitriyu/sharp_ws3/auto/mtrswgwork/dmitriyu/sharp_ws3/sharp/src/am/fabric_update.h",60,1,1,5,20% 
"CaPortType2Char","../auto/mtrswgwork/dmitriyu/sharp_ws3/auto/mtrswgwork/dmitriyu/sharp_ws3/sharp/src/am/port_data.h",56,1,1,5,20% 
"smx_init","../auto/mtrswgwork/dmitriyu/sharp_ws3/auto/mtrswgwork/dmitriyu/sharp_ws3/sharp/src/smx/smx.c",130,1,4,18,22% 
"dev_sa_response_method","../auto/dmitriyu/sharp/to/mtrswgwork/dmitriyu/sharp_ws3/sharp/src/sr/sr.c",30,1,2,9,22%
```

Output :

```
"Function","Source","Line","FnCov","C/D Coverage","out of","%"
"sharp_coll_env2bool","/src/coll/util.c",176,1,1,34,2%
"TreeManager::SortTreeRootsByGroup","/src/am/tree_manager.cpp",1467,1,1,26,3%
"FabricGraph::MadSendRetry","/src/am/fabric_graph.cpp",2170,1,1,16,6%
"ibis_log_mad_function","/src/am/fabric_provider.cpp",93,1,1,12,8%
"__free_context","/src/external/mellanox/alog/src/core/media/alog_media.c",415,1,2,13,15%
"FabricUpdateType2Char","/src/am/fabric_update.h",60,1,1,5,20% 
"CaPortType2Char","/src/am/port_data.h",56,1,1,5,20% 
"smx_init","/src/smx/smx.c",130,1,4,18,22% 
"dev_sa_response_method","/src/sr/sr.c",30,1,2,9,22%
```

Comment: does this guarantee 'remove all the content that comes before the **first** "/src"' ?

Comment: @Kent clearly, no. RavinderSingh13's  solution may be more convenient if you have other characters than `.` and `/`. Link I provided on my solution may guide you to the most robust solution.

Comment: Anyway, please add some extra-examples if you have specific cases that should be handled on your question.

Comment: your solution worked for some cases, but not for this one, for some reason:

"FabricUpdateType2Char","../mtrswgwork/dmitriyu/sharp_ws3/auto/mtrswgwork/dmitriyu/sharp_ws3/sharp/src/am/fabric_update.h",60,1,1,5,20%
"CaPortType2Char","../auto/mtrswgwork/dmitriyu/sharp_ws3/auto/mtrswgwork/dmitriyu/sharp_ws3/sharp/src/am/port_data.h",56,1,1,5,20%
"smx_init","../auto/mtrswgwork/dmitriyu/sharp_ws3/auto/mtrswgwork/dmitriyu/sharp_ws3/sharp/src/smx/smx.c",130,1,4,18,22%
"dev_sa_response_method","../auto/dmitriyu/sharp/to/mtrswgwork/dmitriyu/sharp_ws3/sharp/src/sr/sr.c",30,1,2,9,22%

any iseas?

Comment: Now it removes more than the first "/src/". Is there any adjustment I can do to remove only the first one?

Comment: @OfirMichael I edited using `perl` and non-greedy regexes.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/..\/..\/src/\/src/g' Inputfile
```